# Scan error on column index 8, name "replicated": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type *[]*bool

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlx

I am using sqlx to select a PostgreSQL boolan[] into a Golang struct where the target struct value is a []*bool.

```
type App struct {
    ApplicationID string  `db:"application_id"`
    Name          string  `db:"name"`
    Description   string  `db:"description"`
    Replicated    []*bool `db:"replicated"`
}

var apps []App

err := trx.Select(&apps, "Select * From my_function()")
```

The error returned is: `sql: Scan error on column index 3, name "replicated": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type *[]*bool`

I have searched all around but have not been able to find a solution yet.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only scan into something that implements the [`.Scanner`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Scanner) interface.  You could define your struct as

```
import "github.com/lib/pq"

type App struct {
    ApplicationID string  `db:"application_id"`
    Name          string  `db:"name"`
    Description   string  `db:"description"`
    Replicated    pq.BoolArray `db:"replicated"`
}
```

where `pq.BoolArray` is an `[]bool`, or if you really need it to be `[]*bool`, you could create your own type

```
type BoolArray []*bool
```

and then copy the code from here https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/2a217b94f5ccd3de31aec4152a541b9ff64bed05/array.go#L76 and modify as needed

Comment: Thank you!  With a little tweaking of the Scan code, it is working perfectly!